# Is it possible to close a message window in Outlook using the OfficeJs API?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When a user double-clicks on a message in Outlook it opens the message in its own window. Is it possible to close this window using the OfficeJs API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for [closing compose messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#close). However this API is not supported in read surfaces. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Done - https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/38437894-in-outlook-close-a-read-message-window-with-offic